# Non chemical shield for flying crafts - science fiction?

Tags: electromagnetism

In some science fiction films, especially "Alien invasion" types there is a recurring motive of humans trying to attack an Alien spacecraft with missiles but the spacecraft is defended, at least temporarily by some "invisible energy field" or "invisible non chemical "force" shield surrounding it; in such films, the missiles can be seen exploding when interacting with that shield, while the spacecraft remains untouched at least temporarily.

**Putting alien invasions aside**, Is such shield a real scientific concept or is that total science fiction (at least as of 2019)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173328/123208 I don't believe that this question is off-topic, and I can't find any good existing questions that cover it well.

Answer (score 1):

> Is such shield a real scientific concept

No, for the simple reason that "force" is not a single thing. If you pick **a** force, one can come up with ideas to shield from it, but if you mean **all** "forces", then you have a problem.

I'm trying to come up with a good metaphor but I'll use this bad one instead. You can sell a chair to make money, and you can sell your car to make money. But that doesn't mean a car and a chair are the same thing, and neither one *is* money.

Likewise, magnets exert a force, and your arm can exert a force. But you wouldn't confuse your arm for a magnet, and neither of those *is* force.

You can unwind this by trying to always use the term force as a verb. It's something you *do*, not something you *are*. If you think about it that way, the term "force shield" becomes a non-sequitur. A magnetic shield? Sure? An "arm shield"? We already have those, they're called "shields". But a "force shield"?

But let's look at a specific example. One could, for instance, shield a spacecraft from charged particles by building a super-powerful magnet. This was proposed in the 1970s as a way to protect [space colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_habitat) from solar wind without the need for massive amounts of physical shielding like rock. You can shield yourself from micrometeors with a [thin layer of foil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipple_shield), but that does nothing against cosmic rays, and so forth.

There are things you could do that are universally effective, according to current physics anyway, but would likely not actually be useful. One would be to use a black hole as a sort of dump for absolutely anything. This, of course, presents the problem that you have to move it around to get in front of the attack, and they tend to be heavy. Of course one could go inside the black hole, but that presents the problem of getting back out (unless you have the Heechee device).

There are some currently under-development concepts that might help. The  [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) works by creating an intense gravitational field of a particular arrangement, and it might be that this field would not so much shield the ship as slow down the approach of objects in a certain way. Of course, it might speed them up too, and no one really knows if the Alcubierre metric is actually physically possible, we only know it doesn't violate Einstein's math.

When one does see these things in sci-fi, they invariably have problems. For instance, they are often see-through, which strikes me as somewhat useless against a laser.